# How can I resume the status of a viewcontroller when it is dismissed?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Suppost I have two viewcontroller, namely vc1 and vc2. Each vc have a button, when press, the background will change from default white to black, and a next button.

So the background of vc1 become black, and I click the next button, it push the vc2 with no problem.

```
- (IBAction)nextVC:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *otherView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"] ;
    [self presentViewController:otherView animated:YES completion:NULL] ;
}
```

I do the same thing on vc2, thus the background of vc2 become black. And then I dismiss vc2, and back to vc1, vc1's background keeping black in color.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

The question is, when I press the next button on vc1, the background color of vc2 is not keeping black, it becomes default white. Is there a way I can resume the status of vc2 that I've dismissed? Without saving the data or setting anything on viewWillApper or etc.

**Simply, I am asking a method to resume the view which is dismissed, but not pushing a newly view (vc2).**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use a singleton class to keep your view controller references. So that you can maintains their status throughout the application.

Comment: @Inoka What actually singleton class is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your code of `nextVC`, You are creating new instance of second view controller and push it. That is why you always get white background VC which is just initialised.

So, If you want keep your status of second VC, you need to keep referencing it.

Add `UIViewController *otherView` to your view controller .h file or .m as a local property. And then change your push function.

```
//Only initialise first time. Later don't need
if (otherView == nil){
    otherView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc2"] ;
}
[self presentViewController:otherView animated:YES completion:NULL] ;
```

It should be working.

Comment: Really really thanks fro the help, I can now resume to the status I left.

Answer (score -1):

You can not just resume the "Dismissed" view controller because when a viewController is dismissed, it is removed from the memory and its retain count becomes 0. Your vc1 is keeping its state because it is never being dismissed, you are just PRESENTING another controller ON it. If you want to save the state of vc2 you can set a flag in a SharedInstance or in AppDelegate and then check it whenever vc2 is presented.